# Is possible to assign DHCP global address to a bridging device?

Tags: bridge, global

I have a bridging device(Eg:linux Machine as bridge) that will link two networks. for example my device wlan0 have connection established to one access point and eth0 connected to bridging client.. Now my clients will get connected to that access point through my bridge. Now I could not able to see my bridge as it does not have any ip and echoing eth0 to wlan0 and vice versa. Now my question is i want to assign dhcp ip to my bridge and not statically.. it should be a global and my device only have two physical interfaces eth0 and wlan0... even if i create virtual interface(wlan0:1), i can only assign static ip and cant get dhcp.. I understand that bridge is working on layer 2 and it is difficult to do that.. but please tell me any suggestion that i would like to see my bridging device globally?